# Refreshing OxyPlot graphs doesn't work

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

I have a Xamarin forms application which has an event that runs every second and fetches data from a `Characteristic`. In this event I create the whole layout, set the data and update the view like this:

```
 public void UpdateDisplay (ICharacteristic c) {
   //Lots of irrelevant code above this.
   foreach (Accelerometer item in acceloReadings)
   {
     counter += 1;
     //Y-graph data
     DataPoint itemPointY = new DataPoint();
     itemPointY.X = counter;
     itemPointY.Y = item.yAxes;
     PointsY.Add(itemPointY);
   }

 yAs = new PlotModel("Variations Y-Axis");
 yAs.PlotType = PlotType.XY;
 yAs.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis(AxisPosition.Left, -270, 270));

 y = new LineSeries();
 //Custom color
 y.Color = OxyColor.FromArgb(255, 154, 200, 253);
 y.ItemsSource = PointsY;
 yAs.Series.Add(y);

 opvY = new OxyPlotView
 {
     WidthRequest = 100,
     HeightRequest = 100,
     BackgroundColor = Color.Aqua
  };
  opvY.Model = yAs;

  Content = new StackLayout
  {
    opvY,
  }
  };
 }
```

That code fills up all the models etc and I then want to update my graphs in the same method. I've tried a few ways:

```
   //After all the data is re-loaded and added I want to refresh my graphs.
   xAs.InvalidatePlot(true);
   opvX.Model.InvalidatePlot(true);
   opvX.InvalidateDisplay();
```

However none of these have any succes. When you look at [the official docs](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/common-tasks/refresh-plot.html) you can see clearly it states:

```
"To update the plot, you must do one of the following alternatives:

Change the Model property of the PlotView control
Call Invalidate on the PlotView control
Call Invalidate on the PlotModel"
```

While I've tried all these ways none of them update my graphs/view. When I manually click and resize the graph I can see the data is refreshed. Eventually I want to create the graphs just once in the main method and then update the graphs with the `InvalidateDisplay`.
So, what am I doing wrong?!

Comment: I have the same problem. Tried all 3 ways in the documentation without success. Please post back here if you found an answer to this.

Comment: Sadly I've never found a way and I've switched to other graphs + rendered my own parts. Sorry.

Comment: Old post but in case anyone new has this issue: I recently stumbled on this problem and I could solve it by switching from using a control for the plot to just putting it in MainWindow. It seems like a known issue: https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/1121